# Multiple partitions with same UUID, grub error, cannot boot

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, uuid

I'm quite new to Linux so I thank you in advance for your patience as I'm learning.

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04, and I recently got a grub error at startup -- this one:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-fix-minimal-bash-like-line-editing-is-supported-grub-error-in-linux/
I followed the directions at the link above to fix it, and was able to get into the OS and everything was working fine.  The next time I powered it up, however, I got the same grub error. Now:

`grub > ls` gives me (proc) (hd0) (hd0,msdos5) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1).

`grub > ls (hd0)` gives No known filesystem detected.

`grub > ls (hd0,msdosX)` where X is 1, 2, or 5, all say the exact same thing: Filesystem type fat, and they all have the exact same UUID and size.

`grub > set` shows root=hd0,msdos1 and prefix=(hd0,msdos1)/boot/grub.

I am not doing a dual-boot; I only ever installed Ubuntu as a single-boot.  So I have no idea how I ended up with multiple partitions, no idea why the filesystem of msdos1 changed from ext* to fat, and no idea why they all ended up with the same UUID (which I'm guessing is the cause of, or at least related to, my boot problem).

Edit for clarification: I did look up ways to change the UUID, but the instructions I found required starting from within the OS, not from grub.

At this point I'm thinking I should just reinstall the OS.  But my questions are:

1. Before reinstalling, is there anything else to try?
2. How might I have ended up with all these partitions, if I didn't make them explicitly, and how do I avoid recreating the same problem with the new install?
3. Is there any way to rescue my files from here?

Thanks, MJ

Comment: The UUID tells you the ID is supposed to be *unique* given the Unique in its name.  if there are more than one partition/drive with the same UUID, what happens from there is *undefined* as its a condition that should never exist. You should correct that problem, as what you're asking about is hardware specific (inc. firmware) and may actually differ on just *reboot*, ie. why it's *undefined*, so unless your purpose is to *corrupt* your data - your should fix your issue, and have UNIQUE Unique Universal IDs as intended.  (*based on your title, your question is unclear given title though*)

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  That part I understand; there should not be three drives with the same UUID.  However, I also don't know how to correct that.  I looked up how to change them, but everything I found online required starting from within the OS, which I cannot do, because I cannot boot.  Hence why I am considering reinstalling the OS.  My specific questions are listed at the bottom, and numbered.

Comment: Boot *live* media as you cannot boot any OS on a drive that contains a non-unique UUID. How you boot *live* media varies on device & firmware. An OS won't create a partition without a unique ID (UUID) so multiple identical UUIDs are usually the result of *operator* error (eg. *cloning a drive & not changing the ID, or not using only one *drive* with that *cloned* data drive at a time*).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, @guiverc.  Assuming I'm able to boot from a USB, should I delete these partitions?  rename them?  Will the new boot create a new partition, and will the old ones still cause the same issue?

Comment: If this is a new system, I'd just *clean* install (with format, which will generate a new unique/UUID), but I don't know what else is on your drive, if you've any data that's valuable etc.. so ensure you backup first. If it's a test box you're using to *learn* with, I'd play/experiment & learn.  You can *unclean* install Ubuntu systems, where data survives (assuming desktop, you didn't specify 22.04 desktop or 22.04 server etc) but *unclean* won't format & correct the UUID issue.  I don't understand how you got non-unique UUIDs so I limited in what I can advise, but I'd try & start again

Comment: GParted has the option to change a partition's UUID number. Are any of your offending partitions Live installs? Live installs of the same version all use the same UUID.